# GFortran compiler error on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, gcc

I am trying to compile a hello world program in fortran on Mac OS Big Sur. Before updating everything  worked fine.

I compile with this line:

```
~ % gfortran hw.f90
--> ld: library not found for -lSystem
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed gnu gfortran and gcc before updating. Version command output:

```
~ % gfortran --version
--> GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0
    Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
~ % gcc --version
--> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Output of which command:

```
~ % which gfortran
--> /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

```
~ % which gcc     
--> /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372297/ld-library-not-found-for-lsystem

Comment: See macports mailing lists https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-users/2020-December/049184.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Jan12's answer didn't work for me.

Instead, `brew uninstall gfortran` followed by `brew install gcc` did it for me. I guess the `gcc` installation does a better job at setting the paths, but didn't bother checking in more detail.

Comment: This simple answer worked for me as of Big Sur Ver.11.2.3.  
Note it was required to install the Apple Command Line Tools beforehand by executing `xcode-select --install` (else `brew install gcc` would fail).

Answer (score 5):

I have been able to fix the issue with the help of the following two posts:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666700
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314733/make-usr-local-lib-a-default-library-search-path-for-ld-on-mac-os-x

The problem is that after the update the System library is no longer in the search paths of the gcc. I solved this by adding it manually to the zprofile, so that anytime I run the Terminal, variable $LIBRARY_PATH is set.

**To fix this issue**

Edit file `/private/etc/zprofile`

Add this to the end of the file:

```
if [ -z "${LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
    export LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
else
    export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"
fi
```

Restart Terminal

Comment: Typo? Need a `$LIBRARY_PATH` on the 4th line?

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice since it is empty for me.

Comment: You might need to `sudo chmod 666 /private/etc/zprofile` to make the file writeable.

Comment: Apparently this answer in now outdated. Please use Nigu's answer.